# SublimeREPL and scheme "Cannot find REPL for 'scheme'" error message when transferring

Tags: scheme, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I am using Sublime Text 2 and Petite Chez Scheme interpreter.
I have the REPL up in Sublime and I can run line commands on it successfully, but when i create a .ss file above it and attempt to transfer the file (tools->SublimeREPL->Transfer to File->File) I get an error message saying "cannot find REPL for 'scheme'".

I have found other questions with the same error message but the only issue was that they did not have the REPL open or they were using MIT-Scheme (in which the solution did not fix my problem)

The bin path for Petite is in my env. var. path

Does anyone have any idea what is the issue and how I might be able to get this to work? Thank you!

OS: Windows 7 64-bit
Sublime Text 2 Version 2.0.2
Petite Chez Scheme Version 8.4

Comment: Do you have the scheme REPL open when running the Transfer command?

Comment: Yes i do, I have two rows in sublime. The top is my scheme files and the bottom is the scheme REPL.

Comment: What is the name of the REPL tab? It should be something along the lines of `*REPL* [scheme]` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you MattDMo. I fixed it. It was under *REPL* [petite] because originally the *REPL* [Scheme] wasn't working. I tried to start *REPL* [Scheme] and now it works and the file transferred.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like we need to cmd+shift+p to start "SublimeREPL:Scheme" in a new tab first, thus the ctrl+, and f command can send the script to the REPL in the background.